# I have 30 or so items in a .txt file which I would like to display in a listbox in wp7

Tags: parsing, windows-phone-7, collections, listbox, text-files

.txt file looks like

```
Euro
US Dollar
Australian Dollar
Pounds Sterling
Swiss Franc
```

and so on.
I have tried things like `XDocument` and `ObservableCollection` but can't seem to get them to work.
I would rather not hard code so much into xaml.
thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're sending the file with the project (file Build action set to "Content"), here's what you need:

First, add a ListBox to the Page called CurrenciesListBox, then add this code on the page load event or constructor:

```cs
var xapResolver = new System.Xml.XmlXapResolver();

using (var currenciesStream = (Stream)xapResolver.GetEntity(new Uri("Currencies.txt", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), "", typeof(Stream)))
{
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(currenciesStream))
    {
        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            CurrenciesListBox.Items.Add(streamReader.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to change the filename above to match your file!

This is for starter, there are better ways to do the job (using MVVM)!